# couchbase cbdocloader problems

Tags: loader, couchbase

I am just getting started with using Couchbase and have a problem using cbdocloader

I try this :

> "\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\tools\cbdocloader " -u
>   Administrator -p Administrator -n 127.0.0.1:8091 -b v2
>   json_street_trees.zip {'username': 'Administrator', 'node':
>   '127.0.0.1:8091', 'password': 'Administrat or', 'bucket': 'v2',
>   'ram_quota': 100} ['json_street_trees.zip'] [2014-01-04 21:03:01,460]
>   - [rest_client] [6148] - INFO - existing buckets : [u' beer-sample', u'default', u'gamesim-sample', u'v2'] [2014-01-04 21:03:01,461] -
>   [rest_client] [6148] - INFO - found bucket v2 done

Seems to work but I can't view the documents: there appears to be 23 items eg

> v2     1  23  0    0  94MB /324MB

But 23 is the number of json files in the .zip file (not the individual records)

Then when I try to click on the "documents" it just hangs and doesn't return.

Is it working but just needs more time?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,

- See more at: http://www.couchbase.com/communities//node/add/question#sthash.fk1Hwr73.dpuf

Answer (score 1):

If your documents are large, the web ui will hang because it will try to color & indent the data as a json string. This is a known issue with long content. Try to create small documents instead, if you want to use the web ui for watching them. Ofc, you can get the big documents via your own code too.

Comment: This bug is known both for the detail view (json editor) as well as the index of items. One single large item will make it load indefinitevly - no matter how fast ur browser is. See this post:

http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/stop-browser-freezing-index-big-json-docs